# How do I select multiple columns in a cursor?

Tags: sql-server

How do I select multiple columns in a cursor?
I tested the below code but it's returning/printing nothing.

```sql
DECLARE @DateAdded VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @IdEmployee NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @EmailAddress VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Subject VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DateSent VARCHAR(50)

-- 2 - Declare Cursor
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    -- Populate the cursor with your logic
    -- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
    SELECT 
        @DateAdded, @IdEmployee, @EmailAddress,
        @Subject, @Message, @DateSent
    FROM #tblLeaveNotifToApprover

OPEN db_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DateAdded, @IdEmployee, @EmailAddress, @Subject, @Message, @DateSent

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    -- 4 - Begin the custom business logic
    -- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@DateAdded)

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DateAdded, @ IdEmployee, @EmailAddress, @Subject, @Message, @DateSent
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Initially wanted to print all that columns in each row, but after running the snippet/code it nothing displays, I also tried converting the variables to varchar same result is thrown.

I expect that all the columns of my 7 rows will be print out.

Comment: You select the actual columns in the query that defines the cursor, You then fetch those values into variables. There is an example in the documentation. Your FETCH is correct - the actual query that selects from the table is not. And a cursor that uses an undefined temp table is a bit unusual - but perhaps the code you posted is not complete.

Comment: The best answer is stop using cursors. Sql works really well with sets and pretty awful with row by agonizing row processing. I would be willing to bet that whatever you trying to do here does not need a cursor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think of your CURSOR as a selected set of data from the source tables that you will then iterate through.

Your snippet contains the hints to identify what is in the CURSOR, in your case refer to

```
-- Populate the cursor with your logic
-- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
```

In your case, your are trying to populate your CURSOR using the values from the variables you have declared using the statement:

```
SELECT @DateAdded,
            @IdEmployee,
            @EmailAddress,
            @Subject,
            @Message,
            @DateSent
FROM #tblLeaveNotifToApprover
```

Now, since you have not populated those variables yet they are all `NULL`
What you then do is `SELECT` the variables that you have just declared back into the variables !!!!!

```
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DateAdded,@IdEmployee,@EmailAddress,@Subject,@Message,@DateSent
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

So it is little surprise that when you try to print these you get nothing returned.

Go back to your `DECLARE CURSOR` and ensure that you are actually selecting a data set to iterate through. a CURSOR should generally always be kind of like a temporary table.  If we assume that your temp table `#tblLeaveNotifToApprover` has column names that match your variable names then you need:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DateAdded,
       IdEmployee,
       EmailAddress,
       Subject,
       Message,
       DateSent
FROM #tblLeaveNotifToApprover
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
-- Populate the cursor with your logic
-- * UPDATE WITH YOUR SPECIFIC CODE HERE *
SELECT 
    @DateAdded, @IdEmployee, @EmailAddress,
    @Subject, @Message, @DateSent
FROM #tblLeaveNotifToApprover
```

You need to replace the variables in this SELECT statement with the actual column names from the table.  You don't refer to your local variables until the FETCH statement.